# Unable to Login to Twitter(Twitter4j)

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am using the code given at [Twitter Integration](http://www.ongraph.com/blog/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android). When I use the consumer key and secret given in the website, I am able to login to my account but when I use my app's consumer key and secret, it doesn't login and logcat throws certain errors.

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.feb_1twitterintegration;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "xxx";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxx";
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    EditText sts;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
              StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
              StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            return;
        }
        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            return;
        }
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        findViewById(R.id.login).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        loginToTwitter();
                    }
                });
        findViewById(R.id.tweet).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        String status = sts.getText().toString();
                        if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                            new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter status message",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            final String verifier;
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                //verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                System.out.println(verifier);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Reuest token: "+requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                    System.out.println("after login");
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
                    System.out.println(accessToken.getToken());
                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit();
                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());
                    findViewById(R.id.login).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.tweet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();
                    Log.e("UserID: ", "userID: " + userID + "" + username);
                    Log.v("Welcome:",
                            "Thanks:"
                                    + Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username
                                            + "</b>"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), 1000)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void loginToTwitter() {
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
                    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                    twitter = factory.getInstance();
                    try {
                        requestToken = twitter
                                .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        System.out.println("Req Token: "+requestToken);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken
                                        .getAuthenticationURL())));
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        System.out.println("Request Token in already logged in twitter: "+requestToken);
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");
                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                        access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                        .getInstance(accessToken);
                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    sts.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added the following lines in my manifest file.

```
<data
                    android:host="t4jsample"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />
```

**Logcat :**

```
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674): Activity com.example.feb_1twitterintegration.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40e34cb8 that was originally added here
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.feb_1twitterintegration.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40e34cb8 that was originally added here
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:380)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:372)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:320)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at com.example.feb_1twitterintegration.MainActivity$updateTwitterStatus.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:192)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at com.example.feb_1twitterintegration.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-03 11:13:25.789: E/WindowManager(18674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 11:13:59.422: D/Network(19287): NETWORKnAME: WIFI
02-03 11:13:59.432: I/System.out(19287): Request Token in already logged in twitter: null
02-03 11:13:59.432: I/System.out(19287): ub5i6bEzVcl4nMUCkkgmQEV7DESxcaRU5KkY66bCdz8
02-03 11:13:59.452: E/Twitter Login Error(19287): > null
02-03 11:13:59.452: W/System.err(19287): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at com.example.feb_1twitterintegration.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-03 11:13:59.462: W/System.err(19287):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 11:13:59.542: D/libEGL(19287): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-03 11:13:59.552: D/libEGL(19287): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-03 11:13:59.572: D/libEGL(19287): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-03 11:13:59.572: D/libEGL(19287): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-03 11:13:59.642: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19287): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-03 11:13:59.682: D/OpenGLRenderer(19287): Enabling debug mode 0
02-03 11:13:59.833: D/OpenGLRenderer(19287): has fontRender patch
02-03 11:13:59.863: D/OpenGLRenderer(19287): has fontRender patch
02-03 11:14:01.444: D/memalloc(19287): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52f53000 size:6451200 offset:6389760
```

I have got two buttons as login and tweet. When I use login button, there is no change but when i enter something in the edit text and use the tweet button, I am being taken to a browser which says to redirect but nothing happens after that and logcat shows the above mentioned errors.

**NOTE:**
I have provided the callback URL in twitter as https://www.dreamplusandroid.com.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Been sitting on this for two days.

Comment: System.out.println("Reuest token: "+requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()); is the one. Problem with request token I believe.

Comment: @San see this example may be it is use full... http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/

Comment: Did you create access tokens via the twitter dev site?  Also make sure they are read/write?

Answer (score 1):

In you code

```
private static RequestToken requestToken;
```

is defined but never initialized before you try to use it as line `114`